# Who pays for the gas used when reading from storage or calling pure / view functions?

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas, view, pure

I a little confused about this, i've read that pure / view functions don't cost gas / require a transaction when called, other people say that it does cost, but you're not the one pating for it.

So what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View functions only use gas when they are called by non-view functions inside of the contract.

View functions don't consume gas because you are only making a call to your Node, so you're not asking every node on the chain to perform an action.

You can say that is free but you are limited by your node provider, if you want to make a lot of requests (usually more than 300k a month) you might need to pay your node provider. Or even if you have your own node you are paying for electricity and so on.